# Simulating from Custom Function

Tags: simulation

I am going through an old research paper and I am stuck in one area of the coding. I'll spare you with most of the details but the function I want to simulate from is a complicated multivariate beta function that looks like:

```
mvBeta[rating_,x_,R_]:=densityProduct[rating,x]*mvnCopula[copulaInput[rating,x],R]
```

So clearly, I've already defined other functions. I know that I need to input rating and R. However, I would like perform a monte carlo simulation to obtain vectors of x.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, Jim! Do you perhaps mean `mvBeta[rating_,x_,R_]:=densityProduct[rating,x]*mvnCopula[copulaInput[rating,x],R]`, noting this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/8 ? And what sort of input is `x`? Random real numbers? Some other distirbution?

Comment: This is just a guess without more information, but something using `Map` (`/@`) is probably what you want: `mvBeta[rating,#,r]&/@ xvector`.

Comment: input for x is random real numbers in the[0,1] interval. I am not sure how the map is going to work because I do not have a xvector. Rather, I want to simulate this vector just given rating and R

Comment: `xvector = RandomReal[{0,1},100]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments appended to the question, I believe that what you are looking for is:

```
mvBeta[myrating, #, myR] & /@ RandomReal[{0,1},100]
```

where you can change `100` to be any length vector you like, and `myrating` and `myR` have already been defined.

Comment: Hmm. This might work but now it gives me an error in another place. Would you know how to generate a vector of multivariate standard normals that must have a given correlation matrix?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultinormalDistribution.html `RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[parameters],numberofiterates]`

Comment: Thank you. I understand I need to use the MultinormalDistribution function. However, I am not sure how to make it so that my vector of standard normals have a given correlation matrix, say R.